# Angular material: How to test if dialog.open() is called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material

angular 9

I implemented mat-dialog with following angular material example

https://stackblitz.com/angular/jdvaxxxqoqo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-content-example.ts

```
  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
```

it worked well, but I couldn't figure out how to test  `openDialog` function.

What I should test might be, dialog.open is called, so I tried was

(2020/07/10 edit spec.ts)

```
describe('DialogContentExample', () => {
  let component: DialogContentExample;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DialogContentExample>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DialogContentExample],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MatDialog,
          useValue: {}
        },
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));


  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DialogContentExample);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should dialog open called',() => {
     // create a spy to check if dialog open is called or not 
     const spyObject = spyOn(Component.dialog,'open').and.callThrough();
     
     // call that function
     component.openDialog();

     expect(spyObject).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })

});
```

but test said

```
Error: <spyOn> : open() method does not exist
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

why it said that error even if actually script calls `this.dialog.open()` .
And what is a way to test it ?

Thank you for your kind help

Comment: Are you mocking MatDialog?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Only I did is  adding `provide:MatDialog, useValue: {}` on configureTestingModule in beforeEach() function

Comment: It wouldn't be capitalization on 'Component' would it?  Adding a spy on the class object instead of the instance?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand correctly. I updated my question, adding spec.ts. Should I add spyObject for dialog somehow ?

Comment: When you call `spyOn(Component.dialog,'open')`, where is 'Component' declared?

Comment: component , on this case, it's DialogContentExample,  was declared on beforeEach() . component = fixture.componentInstance;